# Replacing the Contact Dashboard with Views

Tags: drupal-views, dashboard

Has anyone started a project of creating views to replace the contact Dashboard that would show:

```
Recurring Contributions
Memberships 
Donations
Event Attendance
etc.
```

I am considering starting this project and wanted to make sure I did not duplicate any work.

Comment: We have built numerous view blocks and set them to show on the dashboard path in addition to existing. i believe some were for recurring. but while i could share, it probably won't specifically replicate what you are after. PM me to discuss further if you want

Comment: assuming D7 ;-)

Comment: yes, D7, but I get error on import - I think I need views php module installed first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Views block shared [here](https://fuzion.co.nz/blogs/making-d7-views-block-civicrm-recurring-contributions-show-civi-dashbloard) may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: This is great! The views php field with the contact checksum is exactly what I needed! I was also struggling to pass just the recurring ID to the URL without that, it seemed to need the "most recent contribution ID attached to the recurring series" but your view doesn't need that? Mildly confused, but glad it works and I have an example to play with! EPIC

Comment: It will be interesting if I can use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view to include other data on this, such as membership data

Comment: we use views_field_view in a lot of ways so yes expect it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

See https://civicrm.org/blog/brandonferrell/drupal-views-in-civicrm-dashlets

The [civicrm_views_dashlets](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_views_dashlets) module lets you add views to the dashboard, but it does not replace it.

Comment: Thank you, but I am referring to the user dashboard the CMS user can get a link to on their /user page to see their contributions, events, etc. - not the CRM dashboard. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll leave it here to save anyone else being equally confused and suggesting the same thing!  Then I don't know of anything that does what you want, but I'd be interested to see what you come up with.